# gitignore, track all files with some extension, except one specific file

Tags: gitignore

I need to not ignore all files of some extension (json) in sample, but ignore only one specific file with that same extension, for example:

```
# Ignore all files by default, but scan all directories
*
!*/

# track all json files
!*.json

# but don't track this one
Target.json
```

problem is that `Target.json` is tracked, how do I ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure first that Target.json is not already versioned:

```
git rm --cached Target.json
```

That will allow the ignore rule to be applied.

Comment: `git rm --cached Target.json` did the trick because I already staged the file so it won't go away, many thanks!